# Reflecting coordinates over the line $x = -1$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, reflection

I know how to reflect a coordinate over the $y$ and $x$ axis, but is there a rule I could use to help me find the reflected point over $x = -1$?

This is what I know already:

Over the $x$-axis:  $(x, y) \to (x, –y) $

Over the $y$-axis:  $(x, y) \to (–x, y)$

Over the line $y = x$: $(x, y) \to (y, x)$

Through the origin: $(x, y) \to (–x, –y) $

What I don't know is how to solve when reflecting over something like $x = -1$. Is there a rule that would help make solving this easier?

Comment: better? I tried listing what I do and don't know already.

Comment: Much better, welcome to this site! For future questions you might want to read up on [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset the question nicely using mathjax/latex.

Answer (score 1):

To reflect over a vertical line, such as $x=a$, first translate so the line is shifted to the y-axis, then reflect over it, then translate back so the line is shifted to its original position.

$$(x,y)\mapsto (x-a,y) \mapsto (a-x,y) \mapsto (2a-x,y)$$

In this case to reflex over $x=-1$ we shift $x\mapsto x+1$, reflect $\mapsto -1-x$ and shift back $\mapsto -2-x$

$$(x,y)\mapsto (-2-x, y)$$

Similarly for reflecting over horizontal lines, such as $y=b$ involves $(x,y)\mapsto (x, 2b-y)$.

Reflecting over a diagonal line is only a bit more complicated, as it involves rotation of the frame of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting a point over $x=-1$ just means you have to keep the ordinate and let $x'-(-1)=-1-x \implies x'=-2-x$

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Could you explain it using my example?

Comment: @SabrinZ. $(x,y)\mapsto (-2-x,y)$ so $(1,y)\mapsto(-3,y),\\ (0,y)\mapsto (-2,y), \\(-1,y)\mapsto(-1,y),\\ (-2,y)\mapsto(0,y),$ et cetera.

Comment: Okay thank you! I understand a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than think about transformation rules symbolically, and trying to generalize them, try thinking about them visually.  The line $x = -1$ is a vertical line one unit to the left of the $y$-axis.  (You should follow along and draw things out on a sheet of graph paper or on your computer, in order to make them clear.)  Therefore, if you have a point at $(3, -5)$, it is three units to the right of the $y$-axis, but *four* units to the right of your axis of symmetry.

When you reflect this point, you should end up at the same "height" ($y$-coordinate) of $-5$, but this time four units to the *left* of your axis of symmetry.  Four units to the left of $x = -1$ is $x = -1-4 = -5$, so the point $(3, -5)$ reflects to $(-5, -5)$.  We might write

$$
(3, -5) \to (-5, -5)
$$

Similar reasoning shows that, for example,

$$
(-2, 4) \to (0, 4)
$$
$$
(0, 0) \to (-2, 0)
$$
$$
(13, 2) \to (-15, 2)
$$

So in each case, the $y$-coordinate stays the same, but $3$ becomes $-5$, $-2$ becomes $0$, $0$ becomes $-2$, and $13$ becomes $-15$.  If you're a perceptive sort, you might notice that the sum of each of these pairs of $x$-coordinates is $-2$, and therefore arrive at the transformation rule $x' = -2-x$, but if not, you can still reconstruct what's happening.

The point $x$ is how far to the right of your axis of symmetry?  The axis of symmetry has an $x$-coordinate of $-1$, so your distance to the right is $x-(-1)$, or $x+1$.  (This distance is negative if you are actually to the left of the axis.)  Then we need to move to the left by that amount.  We do that by subtracting $x+1$ from $-1$, to get $x' = -1-(x+1) = -1-x-1 = -2-x$.

And of course, $y' = y$.  So, finally,

$$
(x, y) \to (x', y') = (-2-x, y)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The practical approach to figure out something like this is to try out various points and see if you can identify a pattern. I think it should be obvious that the $y$ values shouldn't change, so let's just look at the way that points on the $x$-axis reflect to get a sense of the overall pattern.

$$(-2,0) \mapsto (0,0)$$
$$(-1,0) \mapsto (-1,0)$$
$$(0,0) \mapsto (-2,0)$$
$$(1,0) \mapsto (-3,0)$$
$$(2,0) \mapsto (-4,0)$$

Thus, one could summarize the general pattern as $(x,y) \mapsto (-2-x,y)$.